# Error in data frame, replacement has xx, data has xx

Tags: r, loops

I hope someone can help with this problem - I have been chewing over it for a few hours now!

I have a data frame called 'journeys' as follows which shows a customer ID, their date of travel, mode and journey start time:

```
ID     |  Date     |   Mode  |  Time
------ | --------- | ------- | -----
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  120 
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  130
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  290
1234   | 12/10/16  | Train   |  310
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  330
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  220 
4567   | 12/10/16  | Tram    |  230
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  290
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  450
4567   | 14/10/16  | Train   |  1000
```

So on 12/10, customer 1234 made 4 bus jnys and 1 train jny.

I have written a basic loop in r to create a 5th column which identifies if the journey stages are linked i.e.  the 2nd journey linked to the 1st journey, the 3rd journey linked to the 2nd journey (where 1=linked, 0=not linked), based on the following conditions:

- the jnys are for the same person and take place on the same day
- 2 bus journeys/2 tram jnys/a bus and tram jny/a tram and bus jny are within 60 mins of one another (so a bus and train journey within 60 mins of one another would not be linked). The code is as follows:

  ```
  df <- read.table("Journeys.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",")  

  for (i in 2:dim(df)[1]) {

     if ((df$ID[i]==df$ID[i-1])

       & (df$Date[i]==df$Date[i-1])

     & ((df$Mode[i]=='Bus' & df$Mode[i-1]=='Bus')|  
        (df$Mode[i]=='Bus' & df$Mode[i-1]=='Tram')|
        (df$Mode[i]=='Tram' & df$Mode[i-1]=='Bus')|
        (df$Mode[i]=='Tram' & df$Mode[i-1]=='Tram'))

     & (df$Time[i]-df$Time[i-1]<60)) 

       {df$linked[i] <- 1}

        else {df$linked[i] <- 0}
  ```

This should give me the following output:

```
ID     |  Date     |   Mode  |  Time  | Linked
------ | --------- | ------- | -----  | -----
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  120   |  0
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  130   |  1
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  290   |  0
1234   | 12/10/16  | Train   |  310   |  0
1234   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  330   |  0
4567   | 12/10/16  | Bus     |  220   |  0
4567   | 12/10/16  | Tram    |  230   |  1
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  290   |  0
4567   | 13/10/16  | Bus     |  450   |  0
4567   | 14/10/16  | Train   |  1000  |  0
```

However, when I try to run this I keep getting the following error message:

> Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "linked", value = c(NA, 1)) : 
>     replacement has 2 rows, data has 52231

When I ran this on a test dataset of about 150 rows, I didn't get this error message. I know it's related to the linked column, but I don't fully understand how to resolve it.

Comment: Isnt there something wrong with your curly brackets?

Comment: Yes the last `}` of the loop `for` on your code is missing.

Comment: @JassiL: my answer is not working ? you were expecting something else ?

Comment: Thanks Tim at.  It works, but takes ages to run. My table has 5mil rows. Is there a way to speed it Up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same data as you, and it was working with your code (copy paste it) but the first row. you need to initialized it. `df$linked[1] <- 0`

Here a better use of the if and the condition (faster to read and faster to process for R). 
I also add in comment (cat(i)), if you uncomment it, it is helpfull to see what is happening in the loop.

Last thing, I think you are expecting a 0 and not a 1 for the 8th row, as this is not the same day...

```
df<- read.csv("train.csv", sep=",")

df$linked <- 0
for (i in 2:dim(df)[1]) {

  if (df$ID[i]==df$ID[i-1]) {
    #cat(i)
    if (df$Date[i]==df$Date[i-1]){
      #cat(i)
      if (df$Time[i]-df$Time[i-1]<60) {
        #cat(i)
        if (df$Mode[i]=="Bus" & df$Mode[i-1] %in% c("Bus", "Tram")) {
          #cat(i)
          df$linked[i] <- 1
        } else {
          if (df$Mode[i]=="Tram" & df$Mode[i-1] %in% c("Bus", "Tram")) {
            df$linked[i] <- 1
            #cat(i)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

     ID       Date  Mode Time linked
1  1234 12/10/2016   Bus  120      0
2  1234 12/10/2016   Bus  130      1
3  1234 12/10/2016   Bus  290      0
4  1234 12/10/2016 Train  310      0
5  1234 12/10/2016   Bus  330      0
6  4567 12/10/2016   Bus  220      0
7  4567 12/10/2016  Tram  230      1
8  4567 13/10/2016   Bus  290      0
9  4567 13/10/2016   Bus  450      0
10 4567 14/10/2016 Train 1000      0
```

Comment: Timat, thanks for the response. This works, but seems to be taking hours! I am running through a table that has 5million rows. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: @JassilL If this works, you should mark it as resolved. If your question if about speed (which I did already, not for 5 million rows though), post another question about performance and look at the package data.table